# Foundation Row preventing fullscreen webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make a webpage which is 100% width using the foundation framework, which works fine up until the point where I try to add "div class="row" " container.

What i want, is two images next to eachother, taking up 8 columns and 4 columns respectively. These images should have no padding on either side, and cover the whole of the screen. To do this, i have applied the following code.

```
<div class="row collapse fullwidth">
    <div class="large-8 medium-12 relative columns">
        <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
               <h2 class="brighten">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-12 relative columns">
         <a href="#" class="darken"><img src="img/r3gamersHome.png"/>
            <div class="large-12 large-centered medium-12 medium-centered small-12 small-centered caption">
                <h2 class="brighten">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
         </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

This works almost exactly as I'd expect, except it seems that "row" adds columns on both the left and right side of the webpage which are empty. I don't want this. However, I cannot collapse the columns to remove the padding without the "row" class. So it seems to be a choice of either one or the other. I've found suggestions of adding code to attempt to force full-width, but this doesn't work for me, so I'm looking for other solutions.

```
.fullwidth {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from playing around with it in Codepen ([here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjPxog)) it looks like your CSS is failing to override the Foundation CSS for the .row class.

```
max-width: 100% !important;
```

Rather than

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Fixes it for me. You may want to modify your actual Foundation CSS if you want the row divs to always behave like this.

Comment: How would I go about permanently making any changes overidable? I was under the impression (based on the docs) that foundation was built to be overridden. They tell you too override their css rather than manipulate it after all.

Comment: I believe your custom CSS will override Foundation's CSS if you import it last in the document head. Could be wrong, but give that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: Have done, even used "app.css" as suggested by the creators. Didn't help. I'm okay with using !important if i have to, i just only use it as a last resort.

Comment: Actually, the above might be over complicating matters. First try changing your CSS to `.row.fullwidth { ... }` and see what happens.